# if name exists in combo box do not add

Tags: wpf

When adding a name from a sql table to a combo box in WPF, I want to check if the name already exists in the combo box. If it does do not add. My code I have tried that does not work:

```
        public void display()
    {      
       try
        {             
            sc.Open();
            string Query = "select *from Part";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sc);
            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                String Name = dr.GetString(1);



                if (cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name) != null)
                {
                    cbPartners.Items.Add(Name);
                }

                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("message");
                }
                }

            sc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (!cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name))

Comment: @SoMoS, please add your comment into an answer, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should write:

```
if (!cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name))
```

I think I was the first one ;)

Answer (score 3):

`cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name)` returns either true or false, comparing it to null is always going to give the same result.  Change your conditional to:

```
if (!cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
if (cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name) != null)
```

The method Contains returns the Bool value and you're comparing it to null which is always true.

Change it to:

```
if (!cbPartners.Items.Contains(Name))
```